# why does db.collection.findOne() return less information than db.collection.find[1] in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

why does `db.collection.findOne()` return less information than `db.collection.find[1]` in mongodb

i would think the all return one document in mongodb, but when i run the commands there is some info missing using the findOne method

Comment: is your `db.collection.find[1]` working?

Comment: Sorry syntax error,i should use db.collection.find()[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `db.collection.find()[1]`

If you are using `db.collection.find` **(without the parentheses)** it will return `what a function is doing`

sample output for `db.collection.find` (without the parentheses).

```
function (query, fields, limit, skip, batchSize, options) {
    var cursor = new DBQuery(this._mongo, this._db, this, this._fullName, this._massageObject(query), fields, limit, skip, batchSize, options || this.getQueryOptions());
    var connObj = this.getMongo();
    var readPrefMode = connObj.getReadPrefMode();
    if (readPrefMode != null) {
        cursor.readPref(readPrefMode, connObj.getReadPrefTagSet());
    }
    return cursor;
}
```